# How can I display items from a shared preferences list? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using sharedpreferences to make a search history and it stays, I used its method of setList and getList, but now I want to display the information. When I try to display it I get RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 .

El error es en el metodo  EdadHistorialBusqueda.

Additional data::
-historialMenuPrincipal is a list that I used and there the search history comes out all correct.

-historialbusquedacasteada is another list that I had to cast to string in order to use the setStringList method of sharedpreferences

Here I leave the code:

```
Class ABC{
    IconButton(
                 icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                 onPressed: () async {
                   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                 
                   final busqueda = await showSearch(
                       context: context,
                       delegate: SearchB (
                           "Buscar...", this.historialMenuPrincipal)
                   );
                   if (busqueda != null ) {
                     historialMenuPrincipal.removeWhere((item) =>
                     item.apodo == busqueda.apodo);
                     this.historialMenuPrincipal.insert(0, busqueda);
                     historialbusquedacasteada = historialMenuPrincipal.map((e) => e.toString()).toList();
                     prefs.setStringList("HistorialBusquedaPreferences",historialbusquedacasteada);
                    
}
})

}
Class SearchB extends SearchDelegate<BModel>
{
List <String> historialbusquedapreferences=[];
Future<void> InitRetornarHistorialB() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    historialbusquedapreferences = prefs.getStringList("HistorialBusquedaPreferences");
  }
@override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
  return historialbusquedapreferences.length <= 0 ? MensajeHistorialBusquedaVacio():
  HistorialBusqueda2(context,this.historialMenuPrincipal ); 
  }
Widget HistorialBusqueda2(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child:StatefulBuilder(
        builder:(context,setState) {
    return Column(
children: [
  this.historialbusquedapreferences .length 
    
    ),
  ),
 Container(
 child: Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: historialbusquedapreferences .length,
        itemBuilder: (context,i)
        {
   child: ListTile(
 title:  EdadHistorialBusqueda(i),},) ),
);],);}}

Widget EdadHistorialBusqueda(int i){
    return Container(
      child:  CircleAvatar(
          radius: 28,
          foregroundImage: NetworkImage("http://...${historialbusquedapreferences[i].edad}")),
);}
/////
List MenuPrincipalViewproductFromJson(String str) => List<BModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => BModel.fromJson(x)));
class BModel{
String edad;
 BModel({this.edad})
factory BModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return SearchDelegateModel(
        edad: parsedJson['edad'],
);}
}
```

Comment: You like to fetch list of string?>> `HistorialBusquedaPreferences`

Comment: yes, that is what I want.

Comment: can you print what do you get on `InitRetornarHistorialB`

Comment: when I do a print : example with a length, it shows that an object exists, if it saves, it shows the length

Comment: I can not print historialbusquedapreferences[i] or historialbusquedapreferences[i].edad